# Union of Uncountablely many subsets of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am going  through measure  theory in self study  mode.In lebesgue measure I come across  a problem  that asking  me to
Prove or disprove the following:

**union of uncountablely many measurable subsets of [a,b] is again a measurable set.**

- Now I am guessing that it is not true.
  I want to give the counterexample in reference  to  Vitali's construction  for
  Non-measurable sets.
- Vitali's construction  is given in

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set

- Now my argument is that Every  Vitali set is constructed  by the help of the "axioms  of choice", and I saw each element  as a subset of the mother closed interval say for example $[0,1]$.

As Vitali's  set is uncountable so taking the unions  of the singleton element will also give uncountable union which the  original  Vitali's  set ,a subset  of the mother closed  interval $[0,1]$.
As Vitali's set is non-measurable, so I am done.

Please  give the desired counterexample or the proof.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the long description.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a correct proof. In general, given *any* non-measurable subset $S \subseteq [a,b]$, we can write
$$ 
S = \bigcup_{x \in S} \{x\}
$$
which is a union of an uncountable number of measurable subsets. You may want to verify that

1. The singletons $\{x\}$ are measurable.
2. There are uncountably many singletons needed to get all of $S$ (or equivalently, $S$ is *necessarily* a union of **uncountably** many singletons).

By assumption $S$ was non-measurable and so we have exhibited a counterexample ($S$) to the claim that "every union of every uncountably many measurable subsets of $[a,b]$ is measurable".

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: Thai is I guessed right?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.